# How to make PetaPoco stop changing table names?

Tags: petapoco

I'm using PetaPoco T4 Template (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx), It always converting table names, for example it converts a table named "Media" to "Medium". Have you any idea how can I make it to stop doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .Database.tt file you can tweak the class names to your liking for each table:

```
tables["Media"].ClassName = "Media";
```

I don't know of a way to turn this off everywhere. I believe it is a remnant from the SubSonic inflector. In the SchemaReader classes you will see a call like this:

```
tbl.ClassName=Inflector.MakeSingular(tbl.CleanName);
```

You could try changing that to

```
tbl.ClassName=tbl.CleanName;
```

Comment: Where could I find SchemaReader class? As you know PetaPoco is just a .cs file and I didn't find any class with this name in it.

Comment: Check out the file "PetaPoco.Core.ttinclude" and search for Inflector.MakeSingular

Answer (score 0):

To prevent that, I put always this piece of code in the Database.tt file:

```
// Read schema
var tables = LoadTables();
foreach(Table t in tables)
{
    if(!t.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("tablePrefix_"))
    {
        // Filter tables by prefix
        t.Ignore = true;   
    }
    else
    {
        // This do the trick discussed here
        t.ClassName = t.CleanName;
    }
}
```